# Making a search box using javascript and incorporate a CSV

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to do a filter where I can search terms from a csv file. I really like this example but I cant figure out how to incorporate a csv file into it instead of hard coding it.

I was trying to use this function
d3.csv("dataset.csv", function(data) {

Would really like to understand how this works and how to incorporate the csv file into it.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #myInput {
            background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
            background-position: 10px 10px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }

        #myTable {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #myTable th,
        #myTable td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 12px;
        }

        #myTable tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        #myTable tr.header,
        #myTable tr:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>My Customers</h2>

    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />
    <hr />
    <div id="dvCSV">
    </div>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Upload() {
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
            if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var table = document.createElement("table");
                        var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                            var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                            if (cells.length > 1) {
                                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                                    cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
                        dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                        dvCSV.appendChild(table);
                    }
                    reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried your issue, and found solution on this page: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-CSV-File-to-HTML-Table-using-JavaScript.aspx

Its working, I tried importing a sample csv file. This is how your page looks on using the code given on the shared page, I have uploaded a sample 10 row csv data, and kept your html code as it is.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is nice but it isn't exact what I need. I want to be able to read in a csv file

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [datatable.js](https://datatables.net) plugin. It supports importing/exporting CSV-files and gives you a searchable and sortable Table.

- [CSV export documentation](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/import.html)
- [CSV export documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)